# Received Memory Warning when calling "SetNeedDisplay" method continously in Objective - c programming

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, warnings

Facing memory warning issue due to calling setNeedsDisplay method. below is the process I have done:

Consider my application is to drawing line using `CAShapeLayer` in very large UIView (say: `MyExampleView`) say about `(10000 * 8000)`. In this view am drawing the line by freehand using `panGesture` method. so in the pan gesture method am calling `setNeedDisplay` in “`MyExampleView`” every time so it receive the memory warning and leads to crash the app.

Could any one have suggestion kindly let us know

Code Added:

```
-(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    exampleArea.currentX = someValue1;
    exampleArea.currentY = someValue2;
    // this someValue1 and someValue2 value keep on changing based on hand      moving;
   [exampleArea setNeedsDisplay]; // Here exampleArea - MyExampleArea class is subclass of UIView.
}

@implementation MyExampleArea
{
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
        CGMutablePathRef linePath = nil;
        linePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
        if(!lineShape)
        {
            lineShape = [QlineShapes layer];
        }
        lineShape.lineWidth = 2.0f;
        lineShape.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;;
        lineShape.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
        CGPathMoveToPoint(linePath, NULL,100.0f,100.0f); 
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(linePath, NULL, _currentX, _currentY); 
        // _currentX, _currentY value will change 
        lineShape.path = linePath;
        [self.layer addSublayer:lineShape];
        CGPathRelease(linePath);
}
```

Comment: please share ur code

Answer (score 2):

In every call to `drawRect:`, you are adding a new sublayer without removing any old sublayers. This is quickly going to overwhelm the system with layers.

In any case, you shouldn't be adding layers in `drawRect:`. You should do that in `handlePan:` if anywhere. `drawRect:` is for redrawing the current state, not for modifying the state. `drawRect:` could be called at any time. If it were called repeatedly, your current code would add layer after layer for the same x,y.